# Why is clearTimeout not working for this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I call the following code on mouse click:

```
clearTimeouts();
var inMotion = true, x = 0;
var shuffleTimer = setTimeout(function(){inMotion = false}, 3500);
var shuffleStart = setTimeout(oneShuffle, x);

function oneShuffle(){
    x+=5;
    if(inMotion === true){

        console.log('Shuffling again');

        //shuffle again
        shuffleStart = setTimeout(oneShuffle, x);

    } else {

        //increment spins
        spins++;

        //reset spins if loadOrder been exhausted
        spins === loadOrder.length ? spins = 0 : 0;

        console.log(spins);

    }
}

function clearTimeouts(){
   console.log('Clearing timeouts')
   clearTimeout(shuffleTimer);
   clearTimeout(shuffleStart);
}
```

What should be happening is if I click the elment while `inMotion` is `true` the two timeouts should reset and my `spins` counter should not increase for the previous click. However, what happens instead is that spins gets incremented for the previous timeouts anyway. Why?

Comment: You have `console.log()` calls in there. What is the sequence of log outputs that you see?

Comment: Make the timers global? - also maybe put a mutual exclusion zone around the code that actually _does_ stuff, so that if you clear the timeouts too late then it won't affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What timers should reset? If the code you posted is in a click handler, then each click produces new timers.

The lines:

```
var shuffleTimer = setTimeout(function(){inMotion = false}, 3500);
var shuffleStart = setTimeout(oneShuffle, x);
```

create new timers each time, so the first line (`clearTimeouts();`) makes no sense since the timers don't exist until next two lines.

You should put both timers outside the scope of a click handler, so all click invocations would reference same timers. Also all state (inMotin, spins, etc.) should exist outside the function scope, otherwise each click produces new, unrelated variables.

Comment: Ofcourse - I still have troubles with scopes. I have made them global and they work. Thanks

Comment: @styke You should really make a new Object which contains all state (inMotion, spins, shuffleTimer, shuffleStart) and use that object in the outer scope. Don't just put all those vars in global scope, it's a BadThing™ :). Instead, create a state object in the outer scope (in the same func where you bind to the `click` event).

Answer (score 0):

You should put clearTimeouts() inside your if, like this:

```
if(inMotion === true){
    clearTimeouts();
    console.log('Shuffling again');

    //shuffle again
    shuffleStart = setTimeout(oneShuffle, x);

}
```